# How do I ace the Rookie Test level in LittleBigPlanet 2?

Tags: little-big-planet-2

Whenever I play the *Rookie Test* level in the *DaVinci's Hideout* world, I get to a point where the game forces me to fall into a pit.  The only way out is to open my popit menu and hit the Retry button.  This allows me to progress and eventually finish the level, but the forced death prevents me from acing the level.

I'm sure there's something I need to do to bypass falling into the pit or open a safe path out, but I can't find it.  How do I ace this level?

Comment: It's possible. So was the similar level in LittleBigPlanet 1.  In that game, there was a bridge that collapsed, dropping you in a pit from which you couldn't escape.  There was a sticker you had to place earlier in the level which made it possible to ace the level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ACE the level and get past the part where you have to kill yourself, **you’ll need to get the sunglasses sticker from the next level and return.**

The trick to beating this level is to **stick the sunglasses sticker to the boy's face before you start** your rookie test.

[Source](http://www.gamerzines.com/guides/littlebigplanet-2/littlebigplanet-2-walkthrough-da-vincis-hideout/)

Comment: Wow.  That's *way* more detail than I expected.  I really just needed the last two sentences in the last paragraph.  And where do I place the sunglasses sticker?

Comment: @splattered jeez apparently it wasn't enough detail for you :)  Updated the answer, good luck out there!

Comment: Note that as long as you have a buddy, you can turn off your controller to have your sackboy return to a checkpoint without killing him.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the second pad , take the 2 players to the pit and then disconnect the 2 pads without you or the other player dying.